Why different threads can see different memory operation orders?
The following code is an example from the book C++ Concurrency in Action (2nd edition). The author mentions that threads Ta and Tb can observe different memory states:

Tc observes x == true and y == false.
Td observes x == false and y == true.

As a result, the value of z could be 0.

std::atomic<bool> x(false),y(false);
std::atomic<int> z(0);
void write_x() { // Ta
  x.store(true, std::memory_order_release); // A
}
void write_y() { // Tb
 y.store(true, std::memory_order_release);  // B
}
void read_x_then_y() { // Tc
 while(!x.load(std::memory_order_acquire)); // C
 if(y.load(std::memory_order_acquire))      // D
   ++z;
}
void read_y_then_x() { // Td
 while(!y.load(std::memory_order_acquire)); // E
 if(x.load(std::memory_order_acquire))      // F
   ++z;
}
int main() {
 std::thread a(write_x);
 std::thread b(write_y);
 std::thread c(read_x_then_y);
 std::thread d(read_y_then_x);
 a.join();
 b.join();
 c.join();
 d.join();
 assert(z.load() != 0);
}

Here is my understanding:
Statements A and B are independent of each other, so they can execute in any order. In a particular execution of the program, there will be a specific order, such as AB or BA. For example, assuming the order is AB:

When thread Tc reaches D, x == true, but y could still be false, so ++z will not execute.
When thread Td reaches F, y == true. Since B runs after A, x must already be true, so ++z will execute, resulting in z > 0.

Why is my understanding wrong?
Initially, I suspected that the result of std::atomic<T>::store might not be immediately visible to other threads. For example, even though A has executed, Td might still see x == false, preventing ++z from executing. However, after researching the visibility of atomic operations, I found that if x.store runs before x.load, then x.load should see the result of x.store, as described in this question about memory_order_relaxed and visibility.
So, why can Ta and Tb observe different states?

I don't see the point of the observation.  Ta never sees nor depends on y, and Tb never sees nor depends on x.

It looks like you might have meant Tc and Td, not Ta and Tb.

@TimRoberts: This is the standard IRIW litmus test.  It's not a real-world program, just the bare minimum required to have two readers disagree about the relative order of two stores. It is indeed rarely a problem: release / acquire is sufficient for most algorithms even on machines like PowerPC where IRIW reordering can happen in practice via store-forwarding between logical cores on the same physical core.  (Making stores visible to some threads before they become globally visible, like how even x86 lets a thread see its own stores before other cores do.)

Your use of "before" sort of skips the question; when is something "before"?


In a particular execution of the program, there will be a specific order, such as AB or BA.

This is wrong. You need to use memory_order_seq_cst (the default) if you want that. With acquire/release operations, you only get per-atomic-object modification orders. These cannot be combined into a global order across multiple atomic objects.
